# How to use an OrderedDict Jinja2 variable in my Salt state?

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

I'm trying to write a Jinja macro that will allow me to template a file configuration. The configuration file itself requires certain settings to appear in order. I would like to be able to pass a dict as an optional variable to my macro so that I can override the default settings in the configuration file as well as pass non-default settings.

For example, my default settings might look like this:

```
{% set default = {
   'default_setting': 'default_value',
   'another_default_setting': 'another_default_value',
} %}
```

And my new settings:

```
{% set new = {
   'default_setting': 'new_value',
   'new_setting': 'another_new_value',
} %}
```

Then in my template:

```
{% set settings = salt['slsutil.merge'](default, new, 'overwrite') %}
{% for setting, value in settings.items() %}
{{ setting }} = {{ value }};
{% endfor %}
```

Which should output:

```
default_setting = new_value;
another_default_setting = another_default_value;
new_setting = another_new_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no `OrderedDict` in Jinja2 so you need to use tuple of tuples instead for default settings. Since your new settings are simply meant for overwriting default settings without tampering with the original ordering, it should remain a dict.

```
{% set default = (
   ('name1', 'value1'),
   ('name2', 'value2'),
   ('name3', 'value3')
) %}

{% set new = {
   'name1': 'new_value1',
   'name2': 'new_value2',
} %}

{% for setting in default -%}
  {%- set name, value = setting %}
{{ name }} = {{ new[name] if name in new else value }};
{%- endfor -%}
```